# What will be "reversed" function of line intersected to perpendiculars of a circle?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please excuse me my non mathematical attempt with explain the problem. Please refer to illustrations bellow.

There is a line **L** and a circle **C** with radius **R**. Line intersects with perpendiculars to the circle with given frequency. from those intersections a point is saved where `x = length_of_arc (or angle), y = distance(between intersection point to circle)`.

That this point are being reconstructed on coordinate system where circle becomes curve and line **L** becomes a curve **Cb**.

What function this curve **Cb** is reproducing? Or what function corresponds to this curve **Cb**?

Circle and Line are of  left side, Reconstructed graph is on the right on this picture:
[line_to_circle_and_reconstructed_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usfgc.png)
Saved points have corresponding colors.

If the animate version can be helpful here it is:
[animated_version_gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcYwr.gif)

Comment: I don't know why pictures cant be show. Please click on the links.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow. FYI, regarding your pictures not showing, please read the network Meta post [Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/562482).